# Multiple RAID volume on the same external HDD enclosure

Tags: external-hard-drive, raid, nas, hardware-raid

I was thinking of getting a 5-bay external HDD enclosure with a RAID controller:
http://www.orico.cc/us/product/detail/3623.html
http://www.orico.cc/us/product/detail/6774.html

Both of these models (and many more on the market), are using the JMB394 controller chip:
https://www.jmicron.com/products/list/4

I searched quite a lot but to no avail, so here is my question:

Can I create multiple RAID volumes on the same controller?
For example, if the enclosure is 5-bay I would like to have 3x3TB to form a RAID-5 volume, and a 2x1TB to form another RAID-0 volume then plug this into my NAS to see two "logical" disks?

Comment: since I am not familiar with these 2 devices, I am just commenting.  That being said, I have yet to see a RAID controller that *wont* let you do this.

Comment: Be aware you are running RAID5 a little beyond best practices.  I wouldn't trust the reliability of this solution.

Comment: sorry but i m new to this, does it mean RAID-5 doesn't work well with 3 disks? I thought that's the minimum number of disks required?